# C get element on place without parenthesis

Tags: c, arrays

I created array:

```
int main()
{
    int num[3] = {1, 2, 3}
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get element in place 1.

Why can not I get the element by this code?

```
printf("%d", *(num + (sizeof(int)*1)));
```

What is the different to this?

```
printf("%d", *(num + 1));
```

Comment: Google "pointer arithmetic".

Comment: What is different? `sizeof(int)` is not equal to `1`.

Comment: Integers can be 2,4, bytes.

Comment: Related: [With arrays, why is it the case that `a[5]` == `5[a]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/10077)

Comment: Pointer arithmetic works in units of the type being pointed to, so `*(num + 1)` is `num[1]`, whereas `*(num + sizeof int)` overshoots it by `sizeof(int) - 1` elements.

Comment: Try: `printf("%d", *(int *)((char *)num + (sizeof(int)*1)));` Not sure if this breaks the strict aliasing rule though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you thought incrementing the pointer using `sizeof(int)` will get you to the next member in the array. However, this is not how it works:

when you write:

```
printf("%d", *(num + 1));
```

the pointer advances to the next member in the array (it is an int pointer and therefore when you increment it, it advances sizeof(int) (which is usually 4) bytes). But when you write:

```
printf("%d", *(num + (sizeof(int)*1)));
```

you try to advance the pointer by 4 members (or 4*sizeof(int) bytes), which is out of the boundaries of your array.

Answer (score 1):

for `printf("%d", *(num + (sizeof(int)*1)));` has 
`(sizeof(int)*1))` which is 4 [size of int = 4]. `num` is of type int pointer, which means that the addition `num + (sizeof(int)*1))` will get you to the fourth element of the array, which is out of bounds, because you initialized the array with just 3 elements.

Comment: `sizeof int` is not necessarily 4, e.g., on a 64-bit system it could be 8, and there are even systems (such as DSPs) where `CHAR_BIT` is not 8, i.e., sizes are not in units of 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Indeed, I see your point and you are right. I could've express myself better.

Comment: The first C compiler I ever used (Aztec C/6502 on an Apple][) had sizeof(int) == 2...

Answer (score 1):

The operator *sizeof* gives the number of bytes needed for a given type. As such, this result will change depending on the type and machine, and will not be always equal to 1. For integers (32bit), generally, it will be 4 and you are trying to access *num[5]* which doesn't exist.

You can find more about *sizeof* for different types [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Keywords/sizeof).

Comment: @Arkku yes, rigorously speaking, you are correct, thanks.